# Print from server directly to Google Cloud Print on Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cloud, google-cloud-print

I don't know if it's possible or practical yet, but if it is: How can one print to a printer using [Google Cloud Print](http://www.google.com/support/cloudprint/) from a python application running on [Google App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/)?

For the purposes of an example, let's presume the user is logged into a Google or Google Apps account when accessing the App Engine application, and that account is attached to a cloud-aware printer (e.g. registered printers in Google Chrome with cloud print).

I'd like to print, for example, a PDF file that's stored in a blob on GAE. Let's call this blob `pdf_contents`. I'd like a function:

```
def print_pdf(pdf_contents, printer, print_settings):
    """Prints `pdf_contents` (a blob conforming to the PDF standard) to `printer`
     (a Google Cloud Printer) with the given `print_settings`"""
    # what goes here?
```

I'd like to know how to go about doing this, and whether anyone else has made any efforts in this respect. Of course, I don't want to limit the printing to PDF files, but wanted to narrow down the example.

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [API FAQ](http://code.google.com/apis/cloudprint/docs/faq.html), it's not out yet, but when it is, you should be able to print from an App Engine app or any other app:

> **Will non-Google products be able to
> use Google Cloud Print?**
>
> Yes, we will
> offer an API for any app to use Google
> Cloud Print

Answer (score 1):

Google Cloud Print is not currently a general purpose printing service.  From the page you [linked](http://www.google.com/support/cloudprint/) in your question:

> Where can I print from?
>
> We’re working hard to provide Google
>   Cloud Print integration with many
>   Google products and services, the
>   first of which are Chrome OS, Gmail
>   for mobile, and Google Docs for
>   mobile.

So only Chrome OS devices (netbooks) and Gmail/Docs for mobile can use cloud print at this time.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote [cloudprinting](https://github.com/bradleyayers/cloudprinting) to simplify using Google Cloud Print with Python.

Here's an example:

```
from cloudprinting import ClientLoginAuth, submit_job
auth = ClientLoginAuth("username@gmail.com", "password")
submit_job(printer="...", content=("blob.pdf", pdf_contents), auth=auth)
```

Google has deprecated the *client login auth*, so you should use `OAuth2` instead.